# How to get Attribute value and tag value using apache configuration libraray

Tags: java, regex, apache

I am using Apache Commons Configuration for reading configuration in xml file.
Ex: Configuration is

```
<example>
    ....
    <task id="123">example task1</task>
    <task id="456">example task2</task>
    ....
</example>
```

I want to extract all example.task where I need values in the below form

```
123-> example task1
456-> example task2
```

How this can be achieved.

Comment: Have you read and follow the documentation? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath to extract the information you need.

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("ConfigTest.xml");
ConfigurationNode node = config.getRootNode();
config.getString("example/task[id= '123']"); // This returns the exact value
```

You could also populate a map

```
Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (ConfigurationNode c : node.getChildren("task"))
{
    String key = (String)c.getAttribute(0).getValue();
    String value = (String)c.getValue();
    configMap.put(key, value);
}
```

**Code expert from:** [How to load xml file using apache commons configuration (java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960854/how-to-load-xml-file-using-apache-commons-configuration-java)